# Python 2.7 - Help on pandas_reader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am replicating the code I have got from another website where in "pandas.io.data" has been commented out. Instead am using "pandas_datareader"

```
# Commodity Channel Index Python Code

# Load the necessary packages and modules
import pandas as pd
#import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Commodity Channel Index 

def CCI(data, ndays):
TP = (data['High'] + data['Low'] + data['Close']) / 3 
CCI = pd.Series((TP - pd.rolling_mean(TP, ndays)) / (0.015 * pd.rolling_std(TP, ndays)),
name = 'CCI') 
data = data.join(CCI) 
return data
```

My query is here for line 12 output that I get in the shell

> Warning (from warnings module):
>
> CCI = pd.Series((TP - pd.rolling_mean(TP, ndays)) / (0.015 * pd.rolling_std(TP, ndays)),
> FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with
> Series.rolling(window=20,center=False).mean()

Can anyone suggest how to correct the code?

Answer (score 1):

In version `0.18.0` was API changed - [window functions are now methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#window-functions-are-now-methods):

So use:

```
CCI = pd.Series((TP - TP.rolling(ndays).mean()) / (0.015 * TP.rolling(ndays).std()),
name = 'CCI')
```

instead:

```
CCI = pd.Series((TP - pd.rolling_mean(TP, ndays)) / (0.015 * pd.rolling_std(TP, ndays)),
name = 'CCI')
```

Comment: It is untested, because I have no data.Can you add sample of data to your question?

Comment: Managed to sort it out... by going through pandas 0.18.0 documentation     CCI = pd.Series((TP - TP.rolling(window=ndays, center = False).mean()) / (0.015 * TP.rolling(window=ndays, center=False).std()), name = 'CCI')

Comment: Thx for your help. Pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Super you found solution.